# File Sync (Mirror/Replicate) From source to multiple targets

Tags: sync, git, nas, mirroring, replicate

My situation is this; I need to find a way of mirroring a folder with 60gb+ of mp3 files from a server (or cloud) to at least 100 clients based around the country. All of these clients are internet connected and when these clients leave the place where the Server resides, the latest copy of the 60gb has been copied onto the hard drive to avoid having to download the full 60gb when installed in its new location. Changes are regurly made to the Server side, from new files being added, to ID3 tags being altered (which may not change the file size). I need some sort of solution that will possibly involve the clients scheduled to look at the server & initiate a download of changes & additions, whilst skipping matching files on sever and client.

Ideally a one-way dropbox is perfect, however I can't find anything like this. I've looked at back-up solutions, however these seem to be opposite of what I wish to do (uploading from many to one rather than one to many). I've come across Git & NAS, however not being that technically proficient, I can't understand if they're right for what I need.

If anyone could provide any advice or suggestions on this it would be great?

Also any details i've not mentioned please do ask

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you already looked into [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/)? You should be able to set it up work the way you want. Basically running

```
rsync -auze ssh user@server:/mp3-folder/ /local-mp3folder/
```

on the clients should be enough to get the changes from the server (rsync needs to be installed on both and this example uses ssh so that should be enabled too).

Although git can handle mp3 files it would no be a very fast because it's build for text files.